# grouped_collection_select - group_method changes from Rails 3 to 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

We're migrating from Rails 3.2.13 to Rails 4.0.13.

We use the Rails helper `grouped_collection_select` for nesting `<optgroup>`s.

I've noted that from Rails 3.2.13 to 4.0.2 there were source changes.

http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/grouped_collection_select

Our use of the method is not working currently.

Here our code:

```
<%= f.grouped_collection_select :location_id, @participating_businesses, :"active_locations(#{current_user.id})", :name, :id, :name, {prompt: t('.prompt_select_location')}, class: 'location-selector form-control' %>
```

Here is the error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `active_locations(7)' for #<ParticipatingBusiness:0x005583478f1f90>):
```

Now it's clear that they've changed how the method get's sent.

I'm taking a guess that currently they are grabbing `group_method` option and putting it directly into a `send(:group_method)`, which explains the above error.

However, how could I pass an argument to my `group_method` that relies on the Session (aka current_user).

Looking at source, I don't think it is quite possible.

http://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/4.1.7/ActionView/Helpers/Tags/GroupedCollectionSelect#initialize-instance_method

Should I be looking into re-writing this to work with our goal, without helpers or a tad more manual?

Has anyone run into the same issue?

Comment: Given you know it just passes the `group_method` variable directly to send, what if you tried using `[:active_locations, current_user.id]` instead?

Comment: It's a pretty clever fix, however I tried already and got `ActionView::Template::Error ([:active_locations, 7] is not a symbol)`.

Comment: darn :/ would have been nice if that Just Worked... You may need to feature-request it for Rails. Looks like ordinary `collection_for_select` can take a `Proc` but I've seen an issue that the `grouped` version doesn't work the same way

Comment: I know, that would of been nice and fit well with `send`, but honestly I'm not totally sure that's what is happening. I'll do some more digging!

Comment: @TarynEast, I posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was getting more frustrating.

I've dug into the Rails source for 4.0.13 and the function in question `option_groups_from_collection_for_select`.

```
  def option_groups_from_collection_for_select(collection, group_method, group_label_method, option_key_method, option_value_method, selected_key = nil)
    collection.map do |group|
      option_tags = options_from_collection_for_select(
        group.send(group_method), option_key_method, option_value_method, selected_key)

      content_tag("optgroup".freeze, option_tags, label: group.send(group_label_method))
    end.join.html_safe
  end
```

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/92703a9ea5d8b96f30e0b706b801c9185ef14f0e/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/form_options_helper.rb#L455

It is sending `method_group` directly to `send`.

As suggested by Taryn East,I've tried making `group_method` an array of a symbol and an argument for that method.

However this raises `TypeError - [:accessible_locations, 15] is not a symbol`.

This is raised by `send` since this array needs the splat operator, inside the send call, to work as method arguments.

Now this raises an important question, which is how we're going to answer the initial question.

## How did this work before?

Looking at the source for the old Rails version on Github didn't show any difference, so I used stepped through the code and found this:

```
421: def option_groups_from_collection_for_select(collection, group_method, group_label_method, option_key_method, option_value_method, selected_key = nil)
422:   collection.map do |group|
423:     group_label_string = eval("group.#{group_label_method}")
424:     "<optgroup label=\"#{ERB::Util.html_escape(group_label_string)}\">" +
425:       options_from_collection_for_select(eval("group.#{group_method}"), option_key_method, option_value_method, selected_key) +
426:       '</optgroup>'
427:   end.join.html_safe
428: end
```

That's how it worked before.

Since it was `eval`-ing the whole `group.group_method` method code, it wouldn't raise `undefined method - method_name(args)`.

So the answer is, yes re-writing was necessary.

I got around this by using the `grouped_options_for_select` helper and building an array.

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/grouped_options_for_select